# post keeps data entity framework asp mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In Httppost action method :
I have the following code:

```
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> StudentDetails(string id, string type)
    {
            Student model1 = await db.Student.Where(s => s.StudentGuid.ToString() == id).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

            model1.Type=type;//I didn't submit it yet to DB

            Student model2 = await db.Student.Where(s => s.StudentGuid.ToString() == id).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

            //at this point model2.Type took the same value of type without even setting it
    }
```

why **model2** took the same values of **model1** though I get **model2** directly from database ??!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're not loading it from the database really. The database context (db) has already retrieved that item from the database with the first call.

When you make the second call to get the entity, you're actually retrieving the instance that the context has previously created in memory, consequently, it includes the change you made to 'Type'.

If you want to get a 'clean' copy of the instance then I imagine there is a way to do it. Google something like 'get clean instance entity framework' and read through a few of the responses.

Edit: I would also strongly suggest reading up a little on EF as it seems like you have fundamental misconceptions about how it works.